# How to write an application to stimulate clicking events on Mobile

Tags: java-me, mobile, symbian

I'm finding a way to write a mobile application that could stimulate clicking some buttons on the phone. Based on my check, it's not possible to do with J2ME. How about Symbian? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is

```
            TRawEvent ev1;
        TRawEvent ev2;
        ev1.Set(TRawEvent::EKeyDown, EStdKeyApplication0); 
        UserSvr::AddEvent(ev1); 
        User::After(10000); 
        ev2.Set(TRawEvent::EKeyUp, EStdKeyApplication0);
        UserSvr::AddEvent(ev2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Symbian has a [User Emulator](http://blog.symbian.org/2009/09/30/the-useremulator-a-major-contribution-from-orange/) contributed by Orange that does just this.